# How to run a timer in React component for 60 seconds and call a Redux action every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a react container, where I want to run a timer for 60 seconds and every 5 seconds I want to dispatch an action. This action is calling an api and returning some result.
One more thing to be handled is suppose my action return error after 3rd call i.e. after 15 seconds, then how can I stop the timer thereafter.

```
handleSimulateButton = (e) => {
    /*
        Once I click on Simulate button, I want the below codes to run 
        exactly for 60 seconds
    */

    function runFor60seconds(){
        /*anyRequestFails takes boolean value and I can easily determine 
          its value.
        */
        if(anyRequestFails){
            //stop timer and exit from function
        }

        // I want to this every 5 secs
        else{
            //Calculations
            let params = calculatedvalue
            this.props.callAPI(params)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this? I am learning React and redux and unable to figure it out. The above code snippet is just a pseudocode of my required code.

Comment: You can create the timer using setInterval

Comment: I read about it and i figured it out how to run a specific task every 5 seconds. But how can I stop it after 60 seconds?

Comment: use clearinterval to stop timer

Comment: I coded and it's working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Window.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) can be used to create intervals.

[`Window.clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) can be used to clear intervals.

```js
// Eg.
class Eg extends React.Component {
  
  // Single interval.
  singleInterval = () => {
    
    // Prevent duplicates.
    clearInterval(this.interval)
    
    // Set timeout.
    const fiveSeconds = 1000 * 5
    this.timeout = new Date()*1 + fiveSeconds
    
    // Create Interval.
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    
      // Interval logic ..
      console.log('Single Interval: 1 second ..')
      
      
      if (new Date() > this.timeout) {

        // Interval complete.
        console.log('Interval complete.')

        // Tidy up.
        clearInterval(this.interval)

      }

    }, 1000)
  }
  
  // Concurrent interval.
  concurrentInterval = () => {
  
    // Set timeout.
    const fiveSeconds = 1000 * 5
    const timeout = new Date()*1 + fiveSeconds
    
    // Create Interval.
    const ID = setInterval(() => {
    
      // Interval logic ..
      console.log(`Interval ${ID}`)
      
      
      if (new Date() > timeout) {

        // Interval complete.
        console.log(`${ID} complete.`)

        // Tidy up.
        clearInterval(ID)

      }

    }, 1000)
    
  }
  
  // Render.
  render = () => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={this.singleInterval}>Single Interval</button>
      <button onClick={this.concurrentInterval}>Concurrent Interval</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

// Mount.
ReactDOM.render(<Eg/>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: `// Prevent dupes  clearInterval(this.interval)` Can you please explain this as why this is needed?

Comment: Without that line; if the `start button` is `spammed`: you'll have a lot of concurrent `intervals` with no `reference` to `clear` them (a severe memory leak). I changed the `comment` to "duplicates" to make the code clearer.

Comment: Okay! But suppose that case happens, then we can always take Id of the current interval and use that id to clear that interval. Am I right?

Comment: Correct. I can adjust my answer if you want to run concurrent `intervals`.

Comment: Yes please. This can help me understanding more about JS Intervals :)

Comment: One more thing to remove my confusion. In concurrent `intervals` using id, every interval is independent? Means timer for one start button runs independently of other and hence tasks undergoing will run independently of other?

Comment: Yep. `Interval` content is executed `asynchronously`.

Answer (score 2):

To use a timer in JavaScript you can use:

```
setInterval();
```

In this case you want to assign the interval to a variable so you can cancel it like so;

```
var minute = 60000;
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){ ... }, minute);

clearInterval(myInterval);
```

And to keep track of your failed requests you need to assign a variable outside the scope of the function that's calling your api like this;

```
var failedAmount = 0;

function apiRequest(){ 
    if(failedAmount === 3) clearInterval(myInterval);
    ... 
    onFail = () => failedAmount++;
};
```

For more information on intervals see: 
[Intervals](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)